# Bootstrap Toggle Switch Displays Wrong Content On Page Load

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, toggle, toggleswitch

**UPDATED: SEE BELOW**

I created a bootstrap toggle switch that is supposed to toggle between two different content, and it should show the current content by the direction of the switch and the color black. 
**PROBLEM:** When the page loads or reloads the wrong content is displayed, and the switch is in the wrong side, and the color of the selected text is not black (to signify selected)

[image]

Murad improved on it, but there's still some issues:

[image]

**UPDATED Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/bdqychLw/

**How can I make sure that the page loads the content and toggle switch in the correct order and functionality?**

Please use this Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/jmc798qx/4/

**JS:**

```
   var month = document.getElementById("filt-monthly"),
    annual = document.getElementById("filt-annual"),
    swicther = document.getElementById("switcher"),
    montWrapper = document.getElementById("monthly"),
    annualWrapper = document.getElementById("annually");

month.addEventListener("click", function(){
  month.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.remove("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.add("hide");
  document.querySelector("[type='checkbox']").checked = false
});

 annual.addEventListener("click", function(){
  month.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.add("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.remove("hide");
  document.querySelector("[type='checkbox']").checked = true
}); 

swicther.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  month.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.toggle("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.toggle("hide");
})
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div style="" class="container pb-2" id="signupForm">



<label class="toggler pointer" id="filt-monthly">Monthly</label>
  <div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switcher" class="check"/>
    <b class="b switch"></b>
  </div>
  <label class="toggler pointer" id="filt-annual">Annual</label>

</div>

 <div id="annually" class="hide wrapper-full">
 <div class="container bg-primary">

 <p class="text-white">
Hello This is priced annually 
 </p>
 </div>
 </div>

  <div id="monthly" class=" wrapper-full">
   <div class="container bg-secondary">

 <p class="text-white">
Hello This is priced monthly 
 </p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS[Bootstrap]**

```
.toggle, .toggler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0px;
}

.toggler {
  color: #ddd;
  transition: .2s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggler--is-active {
  color: #000000;
}
x-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}



.b {
  display: block;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
}

.check:checked ~ .switch {
  right: 2px;
  left: 57.5%;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: .08s, 0s;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 57.5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: 0s, .08s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oatv0dp1/

Comment: It still not working, it doesn't load correctly. The text should be selected in annually (selected black), and the content should show annually by default. Instead it loads with all the words greyed out on monthly

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = document.getElementById("filt-monthly"),
    annual = document.getElementById("filt-annual"),
    swicther = document.getElementById("switcher"),
    montWrapper = document.getElementById("monthly"),
    annualWrapper = document.getElementById("annually");

month.addEventListener("click", function(){
  month.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.remove("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.add("hide");
  document.querySelector("[type='checkbox']").checked = false
});

 annual.addEventListener("click", function(){
  month.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.add("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.remove("hide");
  document.querySelector("[type='checkbox']").checked = true
}); 

swicther.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  month.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  annual.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  montWrapper.classList.toggle("hide");
  annualWrapper.classList.toggle("hide");
})
```

I change some code and change variable name for readability. This is work but my opinion this is not valid code.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work onload,what is the problem with the code?  I adopted it from this code https://codepen.io/kijanmaharjan/pen/dMmdej

Comment: What is mean doesn't work onload? Everythink look normal in my computer

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle and code, I added your code, but the problem still remains the words are not selected by default but greyed out, and when you click on the toggle button, all of a sudden both options get selected.

Comment: Because any label not selected first time if you add "toggler--is-active" class label is work normally. I update code this is new fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0kfg9esz/7/

Answer (score 0):

Changed in the html and css the toggle, check, and switch. Feel free to use this.

HTML

```
<div style="" class="container pb-2" id="signupForm">
  <div class="toggler pointer" id="filt-monthly">Monthly </div>
    <label class="toggle">
       <input type="checkbox" id="switcher" class="check"/>
       <b class="b switch"></b>
    </label>
  <div class="toggler pointer" id="filt-annual"> Annual</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toggler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
  color: #ddd;
  transition: .2s;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.toggler--is-active {
  color: #000000;
}
.b {
  display: block;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
/* slide/switch */
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
.toggle input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.switch:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px; left: 4px;
  content: "";
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
input:checked + .switch {
  background-color: #f66;
}
input:focus + .switch {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #f66;
}
input:checked + .switch:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Comment: Your answer has the same problem as Murads, when I load the page both words appear greyed out, when the selected option should be black, and then soon as I click on the toggle button, both options are selected at the same time.